# How does mongo driver choose the node to connect?

Tags: java, mongodb, database-replication

In documentation [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#MongoClient(java.util.List)) it is said mongo driver chooses the closest (ping) mongo node to work with. But write requests can only be processed by master node. Could you please explain on example the way driver uses node to connect? Let's say I have a replica set (connected from machine where driver is used):

```
rs.status()
set: "mySet", members:[
  {name: "mongo1", stateStr: "PRIMARY", pingMs: 900}
  {name: "mongo2", stateStr: "SECONDARY", pingMs: 500}
  {name: "mongo3", stateStr: "SECONDARY", pingMs: 100}
]
```

Driver settings:

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
  .readPreference(secondaryPreferred()) //please mention
  .build()
List<ServerAddress> nodes = asList(
  new ServerAddress("mongo1"),
  new ServerAddress("mongo2")
) //no "mongo3"
new MongoClient(options, nodes);
```

What mongo instance will choose? How will write requests be routed?